# In ARkit Any tutorial for FocusSquare Scene.How to Show models with one touch similar to ARHitCubeScene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I tried to do a project in Arkit example scene FoucusSquare.In ArHitCubeTest when we touch for example if we add a cube it will be instatiated with one touch when the cube is made child of HitCubeParent.Similarily In FocusSquare Scene I made the cube child of FoucusSquareFocused.When the plane is detected it shows the cube otherwise we cant see it since it is tracking.So once the plane is detected how to place the cube with one touch on the screen similar to ArHitCubeTest example.

Comment: Do you mean as soon as the focus square detects a plane automatically place your model then disable the focus square?

Comment: Josh yes...exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most questions, there are a number of ways you can approach this, and please note that my answer only provides a basic solution, and doesn't take into account reinitialisation of the `FocusSquare` etc.

In this example a model will be placed as soon as an `ARPlaneAnchor` has been detected and then will be disabled.

First of all you can add the `Transform` of your model to the `FocusSquare Class` e.g:

```
//The Transform Of Our Model To Place
public Transform modelToPlace;
```

And then add a boolean to determine if our model has been placed e.g:

```
//Boolean Determining Whether Our Model Has Been Placed
public bool modelPlaced = false;
```

Using these two variables an example `FocusSquare Class` might look like so:

```
public class FocusSquare : MonoBehaviour {

public enum FocusState {
    Initializing,
    Finding,
    Found
}

public GameObject findingSquare;
public GameObject foundSquare;

//The Transform Of Our Model To Place
public Transform modelToPlace;

//Boolean Determining Whether Our Model Has Been Placed
public bool modelPlaced = false;

public float maxRayDistance = 30.0f;
public LayerMask collisionLayerMask;
public float findingSquareDist = 0.5f;

private FocusState squareState;
public FocusState SquareState { 
    get {
        return squareState;
    }
    set {
        squareState = value;
        foundSquare.SetActive (squareState == FocusState.Found);
        findingSquare.SetActive (squareState != FocusState.Found);
    } 
}

bool trackingInitialized;

//------------------
//MARK: - Life Cycle
//------------------

void Start () {
    SquareState = FocusState.Initializing;
    trackingInitialized = true;
}


void Update () {

    //If Our Model Hasnt Been Placed Continue Updating The Focus Square
    if (!modelPlaced) {

        Vector3 center = new Vector3 (Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, findingSquareDist);
        var screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint (center);
        ARPoint point = new ARPoint {
            x = screenPosition.x,
            y = screenPosition.y
        };

        //We Only Want To Place A Model When The Focus Square Has Detected An ARPlance Acnhor
        ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {
            ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent, 

        }; 

            foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType in resultTypes) {
                if (HitTestWithResultType (point, resultType)) {
                    SquareState = FocusState.Found;
                    return;
                }
            }

            //No ARPlaneAnchor Has Been Detected So Continue Updating The Focus Square
            if (trackingInitialized) {
                SquareState = FocusState.Finding;


                if (Vector3.Dot (Camera.main.transform.forward, Vector3.down) > 0) {


                    findingSquare.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (center);


                    Vector3 vecToCamera = findingSquare.transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position;


                    Vector3 vecOrthogonal = Vector3.Cross (vecToCamera, Vector3.up);


                    Vector3 vecForward = Vector3.Cross (vecOrthogonal, Vector3.up);


                    findingSquare.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (vecForward, Vector3.up);

                } else {

                    findingSquare.SetActive (false);
                }

            }

        } else {

            //Our Model Has Been Placed So Disable The Focus Square
            findingSquare.SetActive (false);
            foundSquare.SetActive (false);

        }

    }


    /// Performs An SCNHitTest For Any Detected ARPlaneAnchore
    bool HitTestWithResultType (ARPoint point, ARHitTestResultType resultTypes)
    {
        List<ARHitTestResult> hitResults = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface ().HitTest (point, resultTypes);
        if (hitResults.Count > 0) {
            foreach (var hitResult in hitResults) {

                foundSquare.transform.position = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition (hitResult.worldTransform);
                foundSquare.transform.rotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation (hitResult.worldTransform);
                Debug.Log (string.Format ("x:{0:0.######} y:{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", foundSquare.transform.position.x, foundSquare.transform.position.y, foundSquare.transform.position.z));

                //An ARPlaneAnchor Has Been Detected So Position Our Model & Set Our Boolean To Indicate It Has Been Placed
                if (!modelPlaced) {

                    modelToPlace.transform.position = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition (hitResult.worldTransform);
                    modelToPlace.transform.rotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation (hitResult.worldTransform);
                    modelPlaced = true;

                }

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction...

Comment: Thanx josh solved my first part...Now the model should be placed always in one position.I remember you helping me with another question using lookat .I used lookat function but the model is tilted by certain degree..I dont understand why.